# Seeking advice on effective follow-up for postdoc offer letter

Tags: postdocs, job-search, email, norway

I recently sent a cold email to a research group at the University of Oslo for a postdoc position and they seemed interested and asked me to apply to an already open position (even if I was not a good fit for that position - their wording; they said this would be helpful for administrative purposes). We had an interview and they offered me the position to which I replied saying that I would be interested in taking up the position.

We had a follow-up meeting to discuss potential research projects and they asked me if I would be interested in writing a grant that would fund my postdoc fellowship (the decision of which would be out by the time I finish a month or two with them, post joining). I agreed and they said that they would likely offer me a different postdoc position than the one I applied to and once I get the grant, I could resign from it and take the grant up. They have also given me access to their internal wiki and GitHub pages and shared Zoom links to participate in their lab meetings.

In the meantime between my interview and tentative agreement, I was invited for a different postdoc interview (America). I recently interviewed with them and they have offered me a position. They have written up an offer letter and offered me two weeks to make up my mind between the two positions. I reached out to the group in Oslo for a formal offer and they said they will look into it and get back to me...that was a week back and I have not heard back from them.

I am looking for advice on how to effectively follow-up with them to get a offer letter in place. Since they sort of changed the situation a bit from "an already advertised position" to "writing your own grant while temporarily joining a position", I am worried that the situation shouldn't later change from this to something else altogether. Having an offer letter would help me understand what they are offering and raise an objection if they mention something that I am uncomfortable with (for example an offer letter only for six months).

Questions:

1. I have already indicated to them in my first email about offer letter that it will take 18 weeks to get a residency permit...are there other ways I could indicate urgency?
2. Should I indicate to them that I have now received a second offer and that I need to see the offer letter to make my decision soon?
3. Any additional tips/advise/suggestions on how I could follow-up with them?

Additional details:

- Its been 20 or so days since the first email offer
- Their email said that official processing might take several weeks and will be finished mid January (which is about now!)

Comment: Only in academia would you be offered a job and then be asked to apply for a grant to fund your own salary... personally I would not take that job!